# Cannot create virtual environment with pip in it / Cannot run python in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Python: 3.7
Windows 10, 64-bit
Error with creating virtual environment of python using

```
python -m venv envname
Error: python', '-im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

(Environment is created but there is no pip and very few scripts in which there is python, but cannot be accessed)
And when made without pip

```
python -m venv --without-pip envname
Pip cannot be installed while activating environment and executing the following command in it (curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python)
Error: Unable to create process using '<python.exe path>'
```

Comment: What are the result of the command 
```which python```?

Did you try with virtualenv ?

Comment: Yes I did @Nicolas, did not work, said no such file or directory as 'virtualenv'